# Modify ZIP Folder Context Menu To Include "Unblock" Option, Or Other Solutions

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, file-permissions, zip, context-menu

[image]

Is there a way to modify the Explorer zip folder context menu so that when you right click on an empty space while browsing a .zip file in Explorer it will show an "Unblock" option?

I already added this context menu option for regular files by editing the registry, but it only works for browsing non-zipped files.

The end goal is that when I extract the files they will not be blocked. I'm open to other ways of unblocking files before extracting them, while viewing the .zip file contents in Explorer.

Comment: I wouldn't think it's possible, because they "files" don't exist until they are extracted.

Comment: @RobinHood But it's not the files that are blocked. It is the ZIP file itself. When unzipping, Windows Explorer adds the stream from the ZIP file to all the extracted files. I just want to be able to unblock the ZIP file, so the extracted files will also be unblocked. Also, unlike with EXE files, Windows doesn't prompt you to unblock a ZIP file when you open it. If I can't figure this out, I'm thinking of just disabling file verification altogether. Or switching to a different ZIP program. But I'd rather not.

Comment: Also, thanks to Rhys Gibson for the illustration. Although it could also say "Unblock ZIP archive."

Comment: @trkly I'm confused, then why are you browsing the .zip when you try to unblock it. Why not browse the folder the .zip is in, and use your menu to unblock it first?

Comment: Because, when I download a ZIP file, I open the file. I don't want to have to open my entire Downloads folder and wait for Windows to populate it far enough to highlight the file. What you are suggesting is exactly what I want to avoid having to do.

Comment: @trkly Makes sense. I'm with you now.